# postgresql using json sub-element

Tags: postgresql

How do I select only "A" named values from a postgresql database table.

| Id | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | {"results":[{"name":"A","value":"7.8"}, {"name":"B","value":"0.5"}]} |
| 1002 | {"results":[{"name":"B","value":"5.4"}, {"name":"D","value":"4.5"}]} |
| 1003 | {"results":[{"name":"D","value":"4.8"}, {"name":"A","value":"6.7"}]} |

Results should be as

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | A | 7.8 |
| 1003 | A | 6.7 |

Comment: Do you know how to unnest the json into separate rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query to access such an element:

```
select id, 
       'A' as name
       jsonb_path_query_first("column", '$.results[*] ? (@.name == "A").value') #>> '{}' as value
from the_table;
```

This assumes that `column` (which is a horrible name) is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it `"column"::jsonb`

`jsonb_path_query_first` returns a `jsonb` value and there is no straighforward way to convert that to a proper text value (as e.g. `->>` does). The `#>> '{}'` is a little hack to convert a scalar jsonb value to text.

Answer (score 0):

According to column type you can use `json_to_recordset` (If type of column is json) or `jsonb_to_recordset` (If type of column is jsonb)

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=db7302fb77f0c8133cef320fe30e2a78)

- JSONB sample

```sql
select
  t.id,
  x.name,
  x.value
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(("column"::jsonb) -> 'results') as x(name text, value text)
where
  x.name = 'A'
```

- JSON sample

```sql
select
  t.id,
  x.name,
  x.value
from
  test t
  cross join json_to_recordset(("column"::json) -> 'results') as x(name text, value text)
where
  x.name = 'A'
```